# Error using library(caret) in RStudio

Tags: r, r-caret

I have been trying to use caret library for a simple ML application. I am using the latest versions of R (3.4.3) and RStudio (1.1.414). Here is my approach

```
install.packages("caret",repos = "http://cran.r-project.org", dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports", "Suggests"))
```

when I run the code library(caret) I get the following error

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘gower’
```

Now I went forward and installed the packages that it suggests one by one i.e., DEoptimR, gower, etc. This list never ends as once I install a package it will ask for another package. I am so frustrated. I have literally looked up in every forum but it did not solve my problem. I am not sure why the code install.package does not install all the required packages even though I ask explicitly to do so. when I check .libPaths() I can see it has access to both my library directories

```
[1] "C:/Users/omid/Documents/R/win-library/3.4"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/library"
```

would anyone be able to help please?

Edit 1:

```
install.packages("caret",repos = "https://cran.r-project.org", dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports"))
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/omidm/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/caret_6.0-78.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 5155777 bytes (4.9 MB)
downloaded 4.9 MB

package ‘caret’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\omidm\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGuZ1vH\downloaded_packages

library(caret)
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘gower’
```

I also uninstalled R and RStudio and installed them again. Still getting the same error.

Solved:

I managed to solve this issue somehow, however, I am still not sure how. here is what I did

Open R GUI (not RStudio) and run:

```
install.packages("installr") # install 
installr::updateR() # updating R
```

type q() to exit and then open RStudio. Go to Packages and Update all packages

Install package caret as per comments from @chinsoon and @Ronald

```
install.packages("caret", dependencies=c("Depends", "Imports"))
```

if you still get an error about any package just install that one. It will not ask for any other packages as you have removed "Suggest" from dependencies. Hope this manages to solve some people's problem.

Comment: This is strange, especially since you are using the latest version of R.

Comment: can you post the message when you run `install.packages("caret", repos="https://cran.r-project.org")`

Comment: I can reproduce this with your code. Use `dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports")`. You probably don't need the suggested packages anyway. Also, it is recommended to use `https://` nowadays.

Comment: Installing of dependencies is not recursive, i.e. dependencies of dependencies may not get included, and caret requires quite a few packages, so it only seems never ending but it's not. The `caret` package is really a bundling of many different packages under a unified format.

Comment: Installing dependencies *is* recursive:  if `caret` needs `gower`, then all dependencies of `gower` that are needed to load it will also be installed.  You won't necessarily get the "Suggests" packages for `gower`, but you should get everything else.

Comment: When I try to install `caret` and all dependencies including "Suggests", I get a message that some (`R2wd`, `weatherData`, etc.) are not available.  That's likely why it fails.  Follow @chinsoon12's and @Roland's advice, and skip the "Suggests".

Comment: Complete automatic installation of package dependencies has not been my experience even with the use of `dependencies=TRUE`. I don't know if this is because there is a lack of proper recording of dependencies in DESCRIPTION files or incomplete repositories or difficulties with CRAN/Bioc repo cross-dependency pickup. "Manual" correction of the gaps seems needed in many cases. When I look at the content of the Suggests for caret, I conclude that leaving those packages out of the installation will leave you with a severely diminished `caret`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy and simply:

```
install.packages("gower")
library(caret)
```

Answer (score 0):

omg! yes ive been trying to find a solution for days! basically install anything it asks. I had to do the following

> install.packages("gower")
> library(caret)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):

there is no package called ‘hardhat’

> install.packages("hardhat")
> library(caret)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> there is no package called ‘parallelly’

> install.packages("parallelly")

then ran library(caret) and it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).